# Check visibility (contrast?) between text image with transparency on top of background image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I have two images: one with colored text and transparent background and another with a random background (could be anything...solid color, photo, painting, etc). Basically I would like to know how much (approximately) the text will be visible/readable when pasted on the image background and take action to increase the contrast between images if needed. My guess is that I should do some sort of comparison between the color histograms of the two images, but I am not sure which is the right way to do so.

Consider for example the following images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the text is no very readable due to little contrast between text and background. This is just an example, I am looking for a general approach to solve this problem (text and background could be anything).
Ideally I would like to compute the transformations to apply to text and/or background to improve readability (e.g. adding/subtracting brightness, saturation, etc).

I am using python 3, [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/).

Comment: Consider providing representative images and a *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* of your current code to improve likelihood of a good answer.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've added some sample images but this problem is not bound to specific images (the only constraint is that the text image has transparent background). It's more a graphic question than a coding question anyway.

Answer (score 4):

The classic technique is to draw a *"dim box"* behind the text like this:

[image]

as described by Anthony Thyssen in his excellent tutorial pages [here](https://imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/).

So, in your specific case, you could convert the text to greyscale and get its average grey value. If the grey value is light (i.e. greater than 128 on a scale of 0..255) make the dim box dark, and if the average greyscale value is under 128 make the dim box light.

That buys you this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Another possibility is to draw the text twice, once in a bright and once in a dark colour, adding an x,y offset and a blur the first time so it looks like a soft shadow behind the hard outline of the second, unblurred version.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to a similar thing for the background (brighten if text is dark and darken if text is bright). I will give it a try!